# Yii UrlManager routing

Tags: yii

I'm developing a video hosting website. I have a small trouble with UrlManager in Yii config. Easch video in my db has a key like 't9d23f78ld' and I want the user to go to http://example.com/watch/t9d23f78ld to view the video. I have created the 'watch' controller and my urlmanager config looks like this:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.components.UrlManager',
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules'=>array(
            '<language:(ru|uz)>/' => 'site/index',
            '<language:(ru|uz)>/<action:(contact|login|logout)>/*' => 'site/<action>',
            '<language:(ru|uz)>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<language:(ru|uz)>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<language:(ru|uz)>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/*'=>'<controller>/<action>',

        ),
    ),
```

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
    RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

HOW DO SET UP THE URL MANAGER TO VIEW THE VIDEOS AT

Answer (score 0):

Add rule:

```
watch/<id:\w+>'=>'watch/showVideo',
```

which mean, that `id` from url is passed to `showVideo` action.

Also you should add parameter in action:

```
public function actionShowVideo($id) {
    ...
}
```